# firefox document.write() function doesnt work

Tags: firefox, object, document

On firefox browser, the document.write() method is not working. I also tried with document.open() and document.close() but it did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("hello");</script>
```

Comment: how can be this problem solved?

Comment: Why is this tagged `xml` and `stylesheet`?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/axepuj/1/edit) your problem. When creating a [reduced test case](http://sscce.org/), make sure that you don't reduce away the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in terms of syntax with that code as I just tried it and it definitely works fine. Chances are the problems you're having are more fundamental rather than language specific.

Although the document.write function is javascript you have wrapped it in a script block which is an html element. In order for this code to run in Firefox or any browser for that matter, you'll have to save it as an html file before you can open in a browser.

Comment: + embed it inside proper HTML markup:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">document.write("hello");</script></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: this is exactly what I do, however still there is a problem. when I use document.write("blabla"); it doesnt work. On the other hand it is working on ie..

Comment: It works in IE but not Firefox? Very mysterious. Open up the firefox developer console - are you getting any logged JS errors?

Comment: InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable @ file:///D:/TRUVA/TestCase_3.xml:2
ReferenceError: foo is not defined @ file:///D:/TRUVA/TestCase_3.xml:6

Comment: Ok, it seems that the problem isn't with this bit of javascript, but with some other part that is loading in some xml. Because that particular bit of javascript is failing, it is causing this document.write to not even run.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
document.body.innerHTML="hello";
```

Comment: when I use this, only the text stays on the page. the other things disappeared.

Comment: You choose your element and apply innerHTML. eg.document.getElementById("idOfSomeElement").innerHTML = "your content";